# How to remove unwanted text in mail sent through PHP Mail Function

Tags: php

How can i remove this line **via p3nlhg946.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net**  in from address  in the emails that are sent through the mail function in PHP. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
 $to      = 'usermail@mail.com';
 $subject = 'Subject Line';
 $message = 'This is message';
 $headers = 'From: Admin<webmaster@admin.com>' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: webmaster@admin.com' . "\r\n" ;
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I am receiving email like this

**Admin webmaster@admin.com via p3nlhg723.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net**

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `FROM` address, otherwise the default function of sendmail (not `mail()` itself) is to use `root@your.server.hostname` as the `FROM`

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are seeing this on gmail. If you are using the standard mail function without authenticating to your SMTP account, gmail would mark it as sent via the real server no matter which address you provide in the $to field.

You could try using the SMTP method instead: [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)